# accessing html element after it gets loaded using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to execute some code in javascript after one html element is loaded. The html element is generated by javascript code dynamically.

When I try to access the element I want to access I get undefined. I am accessing it in $(document).ready event

like this

```
  alert($("#imgP").attr("src"));
    $("#imgP").removeAttr("src");

    $("#imgP").attr("src", "../../../../images/p.png");
```

How can I wait until the element is fully loaded so I can access it, is there any jquery event I use?

Comment: Can you post your whole JS code?

Comment: It will be better if you remove code from document.ready and put it after dynamically generated dom elements.

Answer (score 0):

If more than one object with same name exist, jquery simply operate on first object. So always give the context, which will tell jquery to find the object in particular div only. If no object find, jquery will not tell you or alert you still the you operate on its property or value.

So replace with `$("#imgP") to $("impP", $("#yourparentdiv"))` or you can check with `$(#imgP)[0]` (it is bad habbit, only for understand).

You can check via debugger before alert or count of object in `$("#impP").length` .

http://api.jquery.com/length/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

You can check .each via

```
$("#impP").each(function( key, value ) {
 alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

Comment: just write debugger above alert and open in ie. on alert what you alert ? after alert just check in debug mode via expanding the quick watch

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on("load", "#imgP", function() {
    alert($("#imgP").attr("src"));
    $("#imgP").removeAttr("src");
    $("#imgP").attr("src", "../../../../images/p.png");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried onload function in html element?

ex :

```
<img onload="function()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Always check the sequence of your method calls. I was trying to access the element even before it was created. Issue solved. Hope someone will find it helpful